# Python: re module beginner

Tags: python, regex

I am learning the `re` module and have a problem understanding `re.search` and `re.match`. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#search-vs-match) gives a good example so I decided to try these out:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile('\d*')
>>> string = "123"
>>> pattern.match(string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='123'>
>>> pattern.search(string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='123'>
```

No surprises here, so I change the string a little:

```
>>> string = "hello 123"
>>> pattern.match(string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
>>> pattern.search(string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
```

Why is nothing found with the last call of `search`? I would expect it return something like this (a non-empty match object):

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 9), match='123'>
```

What happens during that last call to `search`? `Python 3.4.3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your quantifier! The `*` quantifier matches ZERO or more of the previous atom (in this case a digit `\d`). The first match returned is zero quantity at position zero.

I can demonstrate:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"\d*")
>>> string = "hello 123"
>>> pattern.match(string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
>>> pattern.search(string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"\d+") # + is one or more, not zero or more
>>> pattern.match(string) # no match at start of string
>>> pattern.search(string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 9), match='123'>
```

Comment: Oh, I see. However, why does the first `search` return a successful match and not an empty one then?

Comment: Because the first character it sees ***IS*** a digit, so it continues to the next one and the next one. When the first character it sees ISN'T a digit, the regex goes "Oh it's okay, the quantifier says I can have nothing here, too. I guess I have nothing!"